# How to determine which controller has been called from ApplicationController?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I would like to put one method inside my `ApplicationController` and launch it only in case when some controllers are called. Similarly to devise parameters sanitizer:

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
```

I've tried:

```
before_action :recent_discussions, if: :first_controller? || :second_controller? || :third_controller?
```

However `first_controller?` etc are undefined methods.

Is there a way to call something in `ApplicationController` only under specific controllers?

Answer (score 2):

Presuming you meant `||` instead of `&&` in your question's pseudo code (`&&` makes no sense), this would work:

```
FANCY_CONTROLLERS = %w[FirstController SecondController ThirdController]
before_action :recent_discussions,
  if: proc { FANCY_CONTROLLERS.include? "#{controller_name.camelize}Controller" }
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your application controller

```ruby
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # more code

  def special_controller?
    controller = params[:controller]
    special_controllers = %w(first second third)
    special_controllers.include? controller
  end
end
```

And put this in your special controllers

```
class FirstController < ApplicationController
  before_action :recent_discussions, if: :special_controller?

  # more code
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `request.referrer` to get the path of the previous action.

To get the controller responsible for that action, use:  `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.referrer)[:controller]`

Answer (score 1):

You could define private method `def my_controller?; end` in `ApplicationController`, and use filter `before_action :recent_discussions, if: :my_controller?`

Then, in controllers you want this code actually run, redefine `def my_controller?; true; end`